# Phpmyadmin does not accept login

Tags: phpmyadmin

I've done this steps but the last one comes with error (can't find package -y)

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo su 
apt-get install lamp-server^
apt-get install phpmyadmin –y
```

Phpmyadmin is 'avaible' but it doesn't accept login ad password(checked in documentation).
I've installed it without '-y' and suppose it's broken.
Ubuntu 21.04

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're experiencing two problems here:

1. The "can't find package -y" message when installing, which just means you have your arguments out of order. The `-y` flag needs to go before the package names. I just tested my Debian system and an incorrect package name causes the entire command to fail, so perhaps your phpMyAdmin isn't installed after all?
2. Not accepting the username and password. This would be the MySQL (or MariaDB) username and password you use if you have a separate account, or the username root and the password you assigned when installing the package (note that it's different from the system's root user, they share the name but have nothing else in common). A good test of this is to try to connect from the command line client, `mysql -u root -p` (or whatever username you use instead of root).

Finally, you seem to be doing just fine here, but for certain Debian and Ubuntu versions that don't include phpMyAdmin (or where you want a more updated version), you can see the [phpMyAdmin wiki](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/wiki/DebianUbuntu) for installation instructions.